# My final question about comparison test (I have listed all necessary things)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

This will be my final question about comparison test. I have listed all important and necessary things about it (how to prove convergence / divergence of series using this). And I'd like to know if I did it correctly because I will use this list and learn it for my exam. (And I don't care if my description is wrong from a strict mathematical perspective, it will just be for myself and written as easy as possible.)

If we talk about comparison test, there is one for **lower bound** and one for **upper bound**.

Lower bound means we need to show that $a_{n}\geq b_{n}.$

What's best way doing this? We need to make the denominator of the lower bound $b_{n}$ bigger than the denominator of the given series $a_{n}$. Also, the numerator of $b_{n}$ should be smaller than the numerator of $a_{n}$.

What are we allowed to do to achieve that? We are allowed to remove constants in both numerator and denominator, we are allowed to increase a variable (example: we have $n$ and we can make it $n^{2}$) in both numerator and denominator.

We are **not** allowed to remove variables in both numerator and denominator.

---

Upper bound means we need to show that $a_{n}\leq b_{n}$.

What's best way to achieve this? We need to make the numerator of $b_{n}$ greater than the numerator of $a_{n}$ and keep the denominator of $a_{n}$ and $b_{n}$ same.

What are we allowed to do to achieve that?
Same things as in the lower bound. **BUT we are additionally allowed to remove variables in both numerator and denominator.** (especially not sure about that!)

I hope there aren't mistakes / things I do too complicated? If so, please tell me about it because this is very very important for me!

Comment: It is in my view also important that you can actually apply the comparison tests when problems are given. Can you do that? Understanding the theory is one thing, but applying it on problems is another.

Comment: @imranfat I got problems to see whether I need to use the upper bound or the lower bound. And I still don't know if there is a trick / something I need to pay attention at to realize it. Is it possible at all to make a logic decision or I have to test it myself and have luck? :p

Comment: By the way, is everything correct I have mentioned so far? I really like to know that.

Comment: To directly answer your question, there are rules we can use: One for alternating series (obvious which one), ratio test (not always obvious to say that the result could be 1), square root test (similar to ratio test...) and comparison test. So I will always have problems deciding between ratio and comparison. But I will just use comparison if I see in both enumerator and denominator many variables, such as: $n^{4}+2n^{3}+17n^{3}+5n / ...$

Comment: Seems like it is, but if you practice the problems and if needed share with us, that's a good learning process